# Network Request Failed in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

So, I have been trying to find the solution and solve this for the whole day since the afternoon and it's already 10:52 PM here.

Here is the code and it is from the official docs except that I changed the part of logging into the console:

```
useEffect(() => {
getMoviesFromApi();
}, []);

function getMoviesFromApi() {
return fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json.movies);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

The code was partiallyworking in the afternoon, although it may get errors in 4 or 5 refreshes. I have found solutions for requesting data from localhost. Do I need to change the IP address needed to connect to that API and if so, how do I do that? Since, I am pretty new to these, although I try to research many solutions from google, none of them suits me. [image]

Comment: see into the manifest android files if have the permission to use internet

Comment: i'm not familiar with any of this, but I found this line `
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml @FelipeCustódio

Comment: right, try use api axios to do the requests, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios

Comment: @FelipeCustódio I tried, but still no luck. I have ensured to sandwich it with two console logging, but it is the only one that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

lets try this go to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

and go here android\app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml

create this file network_security_config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">reactnative.dev</domain>
        </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean by lets try this `go to android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` but I went to android\app\src\main\res\ but there was no xml folder so i created one and then created the file, copied the code, but still no luck sir.

Comment: In the newest versions of android you need allow the domain to do request inside the app

Comment: can u please elaborate on it, sir? i googled it and got nothing @FelipeCustódio

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#manifest

Comment: this was a guess, i'm sorry I dont know whas happing